# How to change value of selected item in ListView by choosing it from another ListView?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, two-way

I want to allow user to build an action sequence of fixed length. For that I have two list views:
- number 1 displays grouped list of all possible single-step actions
- number 2 displays action sequence to edit

Scenario should look like this:
- user selects an item in list 2, which he wants to change
- this selects the same item in list 1
- now if user selects other item W in list 1, selected value in list 2 should be in-place changed to W

I know, how to do it from code, but trying to figure out if it is possible to make on bindings.

I tried only binding their SeletedItem properties in TwoWay mode, but that's obviously not correct, because there should be some asymmetry between list 1 and list 2.

I guess I need to refer to `SelectedValue`, but I did not get, what's the difference between `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` in my case, when item and value are the same.

**UPDATE**
Here're the sample code for the issue:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="Strings" Type="system:String">
            <system:String>ABC</system:String>
            <system:String>BCD</system:String>
            <system:String>CDE</system:String>
            <system:String>EFG</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox x:Name="SearchBox"/>
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource Strings}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Text, ElementName=SearchBox, Mode=TwoWay}"
            />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you select any item in the list, its value shows up in a `TextBox`. If you try to change text in a `TextBox`, I want selected item to be replaced with new text. But actually, instead of changing selected item itself, when I edit text in a `TextBox`, it affects selection.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two `ListBox` controls with their **ItemsSource property** set to the same source. Set **IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem** to **true** on both list boxes to ensure that the selected item in each `ListBox` is the same.

```
<ListBox Name="employeeListBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeItemTemplate}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>

<ListBox Name="employeeListBox2"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeItemTemplate}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

check with this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx)

Comment: Nope, that's not what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If both the `ListView`s are having same type, why don't you try using **same *Property*** for both `ListView`s.?

This will select the same `ListItem`, if it is found.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: The problem is I need different behaviors for those ListViews. I've added a simplified sample with TextBox instead of List1.